# Arduino wifi shield cannot find IP address

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Hi i'm trying to access my wifi shield's ip address on the browser but I keep getting Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to "IP ADDRESS".

Things I've done:

1.)Updated firmware on wifi shield using this link http://ohmyfarads.com/2013/11/11/updating-firmware-on-arduino-wifi-shield-for-dummies/

2.) uploaded the wifi WPA sketch from arduino site. My connection is WPA2

3.) I switched between arduino IDE 1.02 and 1.05 but no luck with either

4.) I'm using an arduino uno board that is attached to wifi shield

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by incorrect router setup. Things you should look at:

1.You may have to first add device mac address to router list and assign it to the specific IP address you want to have.

2.The second option is that router may give his own address to this device by DHCP.

Remember that you have to choose nonroutable IP address for your shield. IP also has to be in your home address range. The simplest way to check that is:

1.Manu Start

2.Launch and type (or type in search) cmd

3.In console type "ipconfig"

Your local IP is in IPv4 ..........       192.168.x.x (most likely)

(in this case shield should have address like (192.168.x.y).

For more information about IP [look here][1]

You can also use [Netscan](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) tool to find out if shield is in your LAN.

I hope it will be helpful.